# Can I remap mouse keys for games running using wine?

Tags: keyboard, wine, mouse, games, input

I want to play idle-action games (like Witcher I or FTL) with a single hand. These games are both action and idle because you can press spacebar to stop action and think about strategy and what to do next. This pause cannot be remapped to mouse in-game and that is why I asking here. In Ubuntu, is there any possible way how to fake spacebar input every time I press 4th mouse button?

Note: I'm running these games using wine

Comment: What kind of mouse is it?

Comment: @Jeff It is gaming mouse made by Trust. It have standard 3 buttons plus two buttons on left side (pressable with thumb).There is also dpi-switch. I don't have original package for long time already so i can't tell you what model it is because i don't know it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to install [imwheel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/imwheel.1.html) as discussed in [ManyButtonsMouseHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto) under the Mapping More Buttons section. imwheel should allow you to "define application-specific actions to your additional mouse buttons".

So using imwheel you should be able to remap the button to whatever you want and have it only behave like that in the applications you want, in your case FTL and Witcher.

Comment: I see, Thanks. Just one question : Do i need to set it to wine or to .exe ?

Comment: I think you will want to set it to wine.  If that does not work let me know.

Comment: Does not works, prephaps, I'm the one who is wrong. Tell me, is this wrong '#Wine thumbs to spacebar for Witcher and FTL
"^Wine"
None,   Thumb1, Spacebar
None,   Thumb2, Spacebar'

Comment: That looks good to me, though I don't have a mouse I can test with at the moment.  If you look at "sadris" second post on this thread [Wine and 5 Button Mouse](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=753471) it seems he used the game it's self, not wine. So try that. I'm not sure how accurate the rest of the information in that thread is as it is 10 years old, but I'm having a hard time finding much information on this setup.